# Algorithm to get maximum yield

Tags: python, algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

This is the scenario :

B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6 are blocks

S1, S2, S3 are slots

Each block can be put into specific slots.

ie, B1 = ["S1","S2", "S3"] . Means B1 can be put in to these 3 slots.

B2 = [S1, S2]

B3 = [S3]

You can make a product by taking one block from each slot -

ie, the recipe for the product is (1 from S1) + (1 from S2 )+ (1 from S3)

Need a function/algorithm to put these blocks in each slot to make maximum number of products.

In the given example - B3 will be in S3 because B3 is allowed to put in only that slot. However, although B1 can be put in any 3 slots we should put in S1 because to make device we need S1 + S2 + S3 and B3 Can only be in S3. So the best way to distribute blocks among slots will be : B1-> S1, B2 -> S2, B3 -> S3

So we can make one product as per recipe ie, (1 from S1 + 1 from S2 +1 from S3 )

```
Example Input
============
block_slots = {
    "BLOCK1" : ["SLOT - 1","SLOT - 3", "SLOT - 2"],
    "BLOCK2" : ["SLOT - 1","SLOT - 3"],
    "BLOCK3" : ["SLOT - 1","SLOT - 3", "SLOT - 2"],
    "BLOCK4" : ["SLOT - 1","SLOT - 2"],
    "BLOCK5" : ["SLOT - 3", "SLOT - 2"],
    "BLOCK6" : ["SLOT - 1","SLOT - 3", "SLOT - 2"],
    "BLOCK7" : ["SLOT - 1","SLOT - 3", "SLOT - 2"],
    "BLOCK8" : ["SLOT - 1","SLOT - 3", "SLOT - 2"],
    "BLOCK9" : ["SLOT - 3", "SLOT - 2"],
    "BLOCK10" : ["SLOT - 3", "SLOT - 2"],
    "BLOCK11" : ["SLOT - 1"],
    "BLOCK12" : ["SLOT - 2"],
}

Output
==========
{
    "BLOCK8": "SLOT - 1",
    "BLOCK9": "SLOT - 3",
    "BLOCK2": "SLOT - 1",
    "BLOCK3": "SLOT - 2",
    "BLOCK1": "SLOT - 3",
    "BLOCK6": "SLOT - 2",
    "BLOCK7": "SLOT - 1",
    "BLOCK4": "SLOT - 2",
    "BLOCK5": "SLOT - 3",
    "BLOCK10": "SLOT - 3",
    "BLOCK11": "SLOT - 1",
    "BLOCK12": "SLOT - 2"
}

> 4 Blocks in each slot. 4 Products can be made from 12 blocks which is
> maximum yield.
```

I tried the following code :

```
blocks = {
"B1" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
"B2" : ["S1","S3"],
"B3" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
"B4" : ["S1","S2"],
"B5" : ["S3", "S2"],
"B6" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
"B7" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
"B8" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
"B9" : ["S3", "S2"]
}
slot_count = {}
block_slot_final = {}

for block,block_slots in blocks.iteritems():

    for slot in block_slots:

         if slot in slot_count:
             slot_count[slot] = slot_count[slot] + 1
          else:
              slot_count[slot] = 0

blocks_sorted = sorted(blocks.items(), key=lambda items: len(items))

for block,slots in blocks_sorted:
    final_slot = slots[0]
    for slot in slots:
        if slot_count[slot] < slot_count[final_slot]:
            final_slot = slot
    block_slot_final[block] = final_slot

print block_slot_final
```

It gave this output

> {'B4': 'S1', 'B5': 'S3', 'B6': 'S1', 'B7': 'S1', 'B1': 'S1', 'B2': 'S1', 'B3': 'S1', 'B8': 'S1', 'B9': 'S3'}

With this, we cannot make any product as there is no block in S2.

---

Tried another solution which better but still not perfect. Below is the code. 
it gave this output :

> {'B4': 'S1', 'B5': 'S3', 'B6': 'S2', 'B7': 'S1', 'B1': 'S3', 'B2': 'S1', 'B3': 'S2', 'B8': 'S3', 'B9': 'S2'}

```
def get_least_consumed_slot(block_slot,slots):

    least_consumed_slot = slots[0]
    for slot in slots:
        if slot_block_count[slot] < slot_block_count[least_consumed_slot]:
            least_consumed_slot = slot

    return least_consumed_slot

blocks = {
    "B1" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
    "B2" : ["S1","S3"],
    "B3" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
    "B4" : ["S1","S2"],
    "B5" : ["S3", "S2"],
    "B6" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
    "B7" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
    "B8" : ["S1","S3", "S2"],
    "B9" : ["S3", "S2"]
}

slot_occurance_count = {}
block_slot_final = {}
all_slots = []
slot_block_count = {}

for block,block_slots in blocks.iteritems():

    for slot in block_slots:
        if slot not in all_slots:
            all_slots.append(slot)
            slot_block_count[slot] = 0

        if slot in slot_occurance_count:
            slot_occurance_count[slot] = slot_occurance_count[slot] + 1
        else:
            slot_occurance_count[slot] = 1

blocks_sorted = sorted(blocks.items(), key=lambda items: len(items))

for block,slots in blocks_sorted:
    # final_slot = slots[0]
    # for slot in slots:
    #     if slot_occurance_count[slot] < slot_occurance_count[final_slot]:
    #         final_slot = slot
    # block_slot_final[block] = final_slot
    least_consumed_slot = get_least_consumed_slot(block_slot_final,slots)
    block_slot_final[block] = least_consumed_slot

    slot_block_count[least_consumed_slot] = slot_block_count[least_consumed_slot] + 1


print block_slot_final
```

Comment: This is somewhat broad. You can tackle this with all those combinatorial-opt tools like Integer-programming, Constraint-programming and even SAT-solving and free software is available. But it's unclear if that's for example the only product/recipe you got?

Comment: The ```B3 -> S2``` is probably an error and ```B2 -> S2``` makes sense in this setting. It's kind of a nice problem (when evaluating hardness / searching for solution in P; i think it might be in P, at least for this single product-recipe), but i'm afraid it's going to be closed.

Comment: Is the solution B2 -> S1, B1 -> S2, B3 -> S3 also valid? Do you want both of these solutions or is there some reason to prefer one to the other?

Comment: Ignoring (potential?) polynomial-approaches, you can find a prototype (not much tuned/advanced) integer-programming based approach [here](https://gist.github.com/sschnug/eab13d7d79736d5b885724aaf1c67806). While theoretically exponential in worst-case, this might scale well (depending somewhat on the solver). Don't take it as copy-paste code (non-trivial install:CBC+cvxpy), but as inspiration for some approach which probably does what you want to do (according to your example). There are some open-source MIP-solvers available. Without cvxpy, you might need to linearize the objective (not hard).

Comment: The above code now contains a remark, as it *seems*, every basic feasible solution is integral. I don't have the time to think about a proof (or checking the resulting constraint-matrix), but if this would be true, you could use any (high-quality) LP-solver (providing BFSs; e.g. Simplex-based) and those would (under this assumption) scale to millions of elements. (or just use a MIP-solver and he will exploit it automatically and still provide optimums, potentially using exp-time if this assumption is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Pending clarification, this is either a problem of enumerating all maximum matchings (1) or finding one maximum matching (2).

(1) Algorithms for Enumerating All Perfect, Maximum and
Maximal Matchings in Bipartite Graphs
Takeaki UNO
http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/isaac97web.pdf

(2) e.g., Hopcroft--Karp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Comment: (Restricting to one max matching) Can you elaborate? I don't see it yet. The left-graph is probably ```B0-Bn```, but what's the right-graph: ```S0, S1, S2``` does not help, and even if this is somewhat bloated by one more dimension i don't see any ```max-product``` optimization, which is not a characteristic of active edges, but balancing right-node inputs (while maximizing those inputs). I think, including costs, this balancing can be expressed linearily (or at least a-priori linearized), but i'm too lazy to check it for now. Did i miss something?

Comment: @sascha The graph for the example is B1 -- S1, B1 -- S2, B1 -- S3, B2 -- S1, B2 -- S2, B3 -- S3.

Comment: And does this transfer to ```#blocks > #slots``` (which is actually the task imho)? I'm still a bit sceptic (but eager to learn).

Comment: @sascha Some matching algorithms (e.g., the Hungarian algorithm) require that a perfect matching exists (which entails `#blocks = #slots`), but some, like Hopcroft--Karp, accept any bipartite graph and try to match as many vertices as they can, potentially leaving some unmatched.

Comment: Yeah, but this completely ignores that the slots are not binary, but bins/containers (as i understand; everything else makes little sense to me) which can hold multiple elements and the cost to optimize is ```max(min(container-sizes))``` (math opt-costs equal to his recipe-setup). Are we talking about different problems?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bipartite matching problem as described here, and can be solved with the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs